# Javascript document.getElementById('').style.display = "block" NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this section of a website but I can't understand where I'm failing at changing the display style of the images when a radio input is checked...
I've read all the other answers but could not get it to work.
As you can see in the snippet both the images (random images from web) are showing at all times.
Thank you for the help

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #eaeaea;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tipologie-di-ispezione {
  grid-row: 5/6;
  margin-left: 15vw;
  margin-right: 15vw;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.tipologie-di-ispezione h3{
  font-size: 5vh;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
}

.ispezione-left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 55vh;
}

.ispezione-right {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #343434, #212121);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #343434, #212121);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #343434, #212121);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: -20vw;
  height: 55vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ispezione-right img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.tipologie-ispezione {
  margin: 5vh 0vh 5vh 0vh;
}

.tipologie-ispezione label {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #343434, #212121);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #343434, #212121);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #343434, #212121);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1vw 4vw 1vw 4vw;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  margin-left: 0vh;
}
```

```html
<!-- Esempi di Ispezione -->
<div class="tipologie-di-ispezione">
  <h3>TIPOLOGIE DI ISPEZIONE</h3>
<div class="ispezione-left">
    <div class="tipologie-ispezione">
      <label for="ispezione1">ISPEZIONE 1
        <input onChange='sezioneispezione()' type="radio" id="ispezione1" name="ispezioni" value="1" checked>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="tipologie-ispezione">
      <label for="ispezione2">ISPEZIONE 2
        <input onChange='sezioneispezione()' type="radio" id="ispezione2" name="ispezioni" value="2">
      </label>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="ispezione-right">
  <img id="ispezione1img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/fire-inspection-abstract-concept-vector-illustration-vector-id1287434990?k=20&m=1287434990&s=612x612&w=0&h=ThAnvYANbUq-_7BHG0dvauBdot_CaR_TIsUOfRqA690=" alt="ispezione1.png" >
  <img id="ispezione2img" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/qa-tester-developmental-kit-analyzing-binary-code-close-inspection-coding-checking-open-script-website-administration-reaffirming-quality-isolated-concept-metaphor-illustration_335657-1196.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg" alt="ispezione2.png" >
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sezioneispezione() {
  if(document.getElementById('ispezione1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style + "; display: none";
    document.getElementById('ispezione1img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione1img').style + "; display: block";
  }
  else if(document.getElementById('ispezione2').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ispezione1img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione1img').style + "; display: none";
    document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style + "; display: block";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('ispezione1img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione1img').style + "; display: none";
    document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style + "; display: none";
  }
};

sezioneispezione();
</script>
```

Comment: your function `sezioneispezione` is declared but never called

Comment: oh you're right, thank you, I will check if it works rn

Comment: dude [element].style returns an object you cannot append string to it.

Comment: @ArunSharma do you mean like in Matthias Lee answer? I just tried updating the snippet with his solution when u commented, now it's back to how I made it at the start following https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp so I don't know why it shouldn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onChange event is missing on inputs. you have to call function when there is change of checked state of input.

HTML

`

```
<input onChange='sezioneispezione()' type="radio" id="ispezione1" name="ispezioni" value="1" checked>
<input onChange='sezioneispezione()' type="radio" id="ispezione2" name="ispezioni" value="2">
```

`

Comment: thanks, I will try rn

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help, this does indeed solve the issue, i will update the snippet with the working code

Answer (score -2):

You are not setting the style value correctly. You need to set the entire style value, not one style element. Try using `document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style = "display: block"`. If you need to keep previous style changes, try `document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style = document.getElementById('ispezione2img').style + "; display: block"`.

EDIT: as @Json Derulo said, you never call the function that sets the style, maybe my way is not necessary

Comment: this is actually useful but after calling the function I'm still getting the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked') for the if(document.getElementById('ispezione1').checked) line (second line in the snippet)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with element.style.display = 'none' - there is no need to set the whole of the style attribute in one go.

Comment: @AHaworth That's what I had thought, and since I read JSON Derulo's  comment, I realized it was just the fact that the function is never called.

Comment: Yes, I just went back to element.style.display = 'none' but it's still not working

Comment: @Francesco are you ever calling the function though? Also, try running the line of code in the console maybe, to test different code.

Comment: Yes, I just updated the snippet with window.onload for the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null and calling the function but even if it doesn't give any more errors in the console it is still not working

Comment: this is not true

Comment: @Francesco Make sure the script runs after the elements are defined with html tags. Put the function call at the bottom of the code below the elements.